# VB script unable to call a web site : Getting 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, vbscript, iis-7.5

I have a very simple VB script code through which I am trying to hit a website which updates some tables on server side. I'm getting IIS 7.5 detailed error - 404.0 whenever I run the VB script. My website is completely accessible. I'm able to browse it from current machine and other machines. I'm running the VB script on the same machine on which the website is installed. I also tried running the script from command prompt in administrator mode but that also didn't help. Here is my vb script:

```
sUrl = "http://<mymachineName>/mywebsite/api/machines/AssignMachineToRuleSet?domain=myDomainName&machinename=Machine03&ruleSetName=Engineering"

HTTPPost sUrl
Function HTTPPost(sUrl)
set oHTTP =  CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oHTTP.open "GET", sUrl, false, "<DomainName>\Administrator", "Passw0rd"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
oHTTP.send
response = oHTTP.responseText
Wscript.Echo response
End Function
```

I also tried changing the version of "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" to MSXML2.XMLHTTP and MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0 but all give very same error. My website is written in ASP.Net MVC. It is hosted in IIS. Website's application pool is running under Network Service account which is a built-in NT Authority account. I tried capturing the request being sent to IIS through fiddler but it shows no requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry to bother you all. It was my mistake. Actually in the URL `http://<mymachineName>/mywebsite/api/machines/AssignMachineToRuleSet?domain=myDomainName&machinename=Machine03&ruleSetName=Engineering` I was giving the website name incorrectly. Somehow the name of directory on disk corresponding to the website was different from the name of virtual directory created in IIS. I was trying to call the website using the directory name found on disk. I should have actually been using the virtual directory name assigned in the IIS while creating the website. It worked the moment I changed the URL to point to virtual directory corresponding to the website. Name of the virtual directory was `myweb` instead of `mywebsite`. VB script had no error.